# Returning percentage of area of polygon intersecting another polygon using shapely

Tags: shapely

Using the shapely library, suppose I have a `shp` file *V* and another `shp` file *Z*. For each polygon *v* in *V*, and for each polygon *z* in *Z*, I would like to know what percentage of the area of *z* falls within (intersects) *v*.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Next code:

```
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import shape

path1 = '/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/polygon1.shp'
path2 = '/home/zeito/pyqgis_data/polygon8.shp'

polygon1 = fiona.open(path1)
polygon8 = fiona.open(path2)

geom_p1 = [ shape(feat["geometry"]) for feat in polygon1 ]
geom_p8 = [ shape(feat["geometry"]) for feat in polygon8 ]

for i, g1 in enumerate(geom_p1):
    for j, g8 in enumerate(geom_p8):
        if g1.intersects(g8):
            print i, j, (g1.intersection(g8).area/g1.area)*100
```

for this situation:

[image]

it produces indexes and area percentages (related to polygon1 area) for each feature in polygon8.

```
0 1 22.1984674733
0 4 2.79999613843
0 6 12.7848188532
```